# Conectarme por SSH a PC con Windows 10 desde Linux usando clave prviada

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

Lo estoy intentando hace días y no puedo, hasta ahora intenté esto:

En PC con Ubunutu server 20 le doy un nombre a la clave

> ssh-keygen

> eval $(ssh-keygen)

> ssh-add y elijo la clave privada

Luego en el PC con Windows 10 creo la carpeta, bajo la carpeta de mi usuario, *.ssh*, y ahí creo un archivo llamado *authorized_keys* y en cada línea pongo una clave pública, en este caso la que generé anteriormente. - Reinicio el servidor

Cuando intento conectarme luego desde el PC con Linux, me sigue pidiendo la contraseña y no indica nada sobre si al menos intentó utilizar la clave privada
el comando que uso es:

> ssh -i "/home/mathias/.ssh/Windows10FromUbuserver" usuariodeWindowsRemoto@direccionIPDestino

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo aplicando esta solución: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1358#issuecomment-496818710